# Generate two different random numbers of size n in a C using a function

Tags: c, function, duplicates

I need to generate two random numbers of n-digits in a C program using a function. I am getting same values for both variables `num1` and `num2`. Is it because of the faster processor that the instructions are executed without a precise change in time point by the `srand()` and both values are same? Can I add a time delay to get different values?

I am using two generate functions, one without `srand()` to get a different value. Does any other optimal solution exist?

```
long generate(int n)
{
  int a[n];
  srand(time(0));
  a[0] = rand() % 9 + 1;
  for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)
    a[i] = rand() % 10;

  long num = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    num = 10 * num + a[i];
  return num;
}

int main()
{
  int num1 = generate(5);
  int num2 = generate(5);
  printf("%ld   %ld",a,b);  
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: If you want TO REALLY UNDERSTAND WHY, research *pseudo-random numbers generators*.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi No need for screaming - the dup should do

Comment: @4386427 I am not screaming in a bad way. Just so that the OP does hear me.